# Pulling picture UUIDs for a known set of users on Apigee

Tags: database, apigee

I am trying to come up with the best strategy to accomplish the following on Apigee platform: I have "teams" of users, and I'd like each of the users within the team to be able to see pictures of the rest of the team. Correspondingly I want to prevent people from different teams from seeing each other's pictures. (Oh, and each user can be in multiple teams).
I want to set up an Apigee group corresponding to each team, and give the group "GET" permissions to the profiles of all the users within the team. I think this should restrict permissions the way I want it to be. My main concern is this. Basically I want to have a screen in my app that will show a list of users on the team, with thumbnails of their pictures. Is there a good way to pull in all the user entries with a single query?
I can imagine doing something like this:

```
[appDelegate.dataClient setDelegate:self];
for(NSString *user in usernames) {
    ApigeeQuery *teamQuery = [[ApigeeQuery alloc] init];
    [teamQuery addRequiredOperation:@"username" op:kApigeeQueryOperationEquals valueStr:user];

    [appDelegate.dataClient getEntities:@"users" query:teamQuery];    
}
```

And then processing the responses to my asynchronous queries. But is there a better way, preferably with a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use Usergrid groups.  Create a group for each team and add users to the groups.  The list of groups a user belongs to can be found via a GET request on:
    /users/user name or uuid/groups
For each group, you find the users by doing a GET request on:
    /groups/group uuid, retrieved above/users

This approach would allow you to get all of the user profiles a user is allowed to see by iterating through all the groups.  You could have a page section for each group and list each member or create one consolidated list for the user and display it that way.   A user would only see the profiles of people with whom he shares a group with.

Comment: Hi Mike, you are right. Looking back at the documentation for groups I realized that listing users within a group returns full user profiles. For some reason I previously assumed that it would just return a list of user names or user UUIDs.

Comment: But I'm afraid now I have to ask a follow-up question :) It turns out that if I simply create a group, add some users there, and don't set up additional permissions, then a user in that group can't list users ("user doesn't have permissions" error). I found that the only way I can make it work is if I give my test user GET permission for "/groups/my-group/users" (can't be simply "/groups/my-group"). Is this the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to do this.  My apologies for not pointing this out sooner.  The app I was using had relaxed privileges.  One thing you could try (that I haven't tested) is creating a role that has GET permissions on either "/groups/*/*" or "/groups/**" and assigning that to every user.  Please try both if one doesn't work.  If neither work, you're going to have to explicitly set permissions on "/groups/my-group/users" for each user in the group.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the pictures of the developers and the apis to get the listing/pictures are all available with you; and you are using Apigee to restrict access to these APIs.

My suggestion would be to take a look at the concept of [companies](http://apigee.com/docs/api/companies-0) supported by Apigee. Though the concept is called companies, its a way to group developers - more details you can find on the documentation page.

The companies can correspond to your teams and you can have custom attribute on the company containing the team name.

When a request arrives, the proxy would first determine the company to which the developer making the request belongs to. Use the custom attribute to determine the team name; send the team name to the backend to do the rest of processing(listing,serving pictures) as you mention.

Let me know if this line of thought works for you.

Comment: I can't really see how using companies in my case is better than using groups. My users are not actually developers, so I guess using groups is fine. You also seem  to imply that I would need to do listing and serving pictures through my own server. But that is one thing that I'm trying to avoid here. I believe this whole process can be handled just between the client (my app) and Apigee server.